# bash + getting the headers from a file and numbering them

Tags: bash

This gets all the headers in a file

```
$head -n 1 basicFile.csv | tr ',' '\n'
    header1
    header2
    header3
    header4
    header5
    header6
    header7
    header8
    header9
    header10
```

what I want is to add the header number to the left 
to get something like:

```
1:header1
...
10:header10
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
head -n 1 basicFile.csv | tr ',' '\n' | cat -n
```

Not *exactly* the output you specified, but pretty close.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a shorter way of doing it with `awk`, but this works:

```
oldIFS=$IFS   
IFS=','
i=1
for header in $(head -n 1 basicFile.cs); do
  echo ${i}:$header
  ((i++))
done
IFS=$oldIFS
```

Comment: there is spaces in the header names, this will then print every a number for every word

Comment: @HattrickNZ: fixed. Rather than changing the text to match the IFS, change the IFS to match your text.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a simple counter and for loop:

```
COUNTER=1
for h in $(head -n 1 basicFile.csv | tr ',' '\n')
do
   printf "%d:%s\n" "$COUNTER" "$h"
   (( COUNTER++ ))
done
```

Comment: That will give unexpected results if any of the headers contains spaces: `for` iterates over *words* not lines.

Comment: there is spaces in the header names, this will then print every a number for every word

Comment: @glennjackman hmm good point, it worked fine for me because I used the example above

Answer (score 0):

It depends, just the shell or is awk good enough?

```
% cat count_headers
cnt=1 ; head -n 1 "$1" | tr ',' '\n' | while read header ; do 
   printf "%d:%s\n" $cnt "$header"
   cnt=$(($cnt+1))
done
% sh count_headers basicFile.csv
1:...
...
% awk -F, 'NR==1 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print i ":" $i}' basicFile.csv
1:...
...
%
```